# Get selected option via change listener

Tags: html, typescript, forms, event-listener

How to get the selected option via change listener with TypeScript?
I have found JavaScript examples where the value is obtained via `event.`, but I could not find any field that contained the selected option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Select:</label>
      <select id="select1">
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
window.addEventListener("load", handleLoad);

function handleLoad(event: Event): void {
  let select: HTMLDivElement = <HTMLDivElement>(
    document.querySelector("#select1")
  );
  select.addEventListener("change", getSelectedOption);
}

function getSelectedOption(event: Event): void {
  console.log("Selected option:", event);
}
```

Comment: `console.log("Selected option:", event.target.value);` No different with or without TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks, but that will show:  error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks bloodyKnuckles, I found the solution via the resulting error message:

```
function getSelectedOption(event: Event): void {
  console.log("Selected option:", (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value);
```